# Checking contents of a register in SPARC Assembly

Tags: loops, debugging, assembly, printing, sparc

Is there a way to print the contents of a register if I'm expecting numbers? I know of printf, but I've been told and seen that it uses the first char of a string as an argument. What I want to do for debugging (for things such as loop iterations) is be able to check registers during run time by printing what they hold after commands such as:

```
mov      %i0, %o0
mov      %i1, %o1
mov      %i2, %o2 
add      %i1, %l1, %o2
sub      %l1, 1, %o1
dec      %l2
```

Comment: Use a debugger, or `printf` with a format string of course. But make sure other registers are unchanged.

Comment: So I could make a format string with the contents of a register?